# Why am i getting this Kernel Error in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Why am i getting this Kernel Error in jupyter notebook?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 100, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 53, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: It would be wise to tell platform, distribution, version etc

Comment: How did you start the notebook session?